# AVPlayer View Controller Autorotation off?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, autorotate

I'm working on an iOS app in portrait mode only, and it's working fine.

Issue is that I'm presenting **AVPlayerViewController** above navigationController (both created programmatically). This player supports all the rotations (I don't know why!).

I want to fix this to **portrait mode only** just like other sections of app.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create new class that inherits from AVPlayerViewController and implement the supported interface method like this. After this instead of initializing object of AVPlayerViewController just create object of the class that you have created.

```
class MyPortraitVideoController: AVPlayerViewController {


    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

**Edited to add**:

Note that the [Documentation for `AVPlayerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller) states:

> **Important**
>  Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this
>   class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

As this is the accepted answer, I assume the OP has tried it and it worked, but I thought I should add a note about it here to make sure future readers are aware of any potential problems.  Undefined behavior means this could stop working in a future release of iOS.

Comment: yes, i just tried this and was about to post the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Then i must've up vote u too. 'Cause you've got your answer without anyones help.

Comment: Seems like the right answer, except for this:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller.  "Important: Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController.  Overriding this class's methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior."

Comment: @JeffLoughlin, thanks for the comment.
In this scenerio, do you have any idea how can i fix the issue (Without using subclass) ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to restricted landscape orientation for some views.So I set **supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor** as **portrait** in **AppDelegate**. When I present AVPlayerViewController I had to set **supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor** as **all** in **AppDelegate**.
Check below codes as well.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var shouldSupportLandscape = Bool()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
     if self.shouldSupportLandscape == true {
          return .all
      }else {
          return .portrait
      }   
 }
```

**When present AVPlayerViewController**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.shouldSupportLandscape = true
```

**When dismiss AVPlayerViewController**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.shouldSupportLandscape = false
```